# mapping two fields from one table on to other

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, cascade

I have these 2 tables

```
Users(
   id PK,
   name VARCHAR(30)
);
```

The other table is

```
Orders(
  id PK,
  orderBy FK Users.id,
  orderTo FK Users.id
);
```

Now, what I want to do is to create `Orders` entity class which maps `orderBy` and `orderTo` to the user. But the most thing i am confuse about is what cascading i should use.

```
class Orders{
   ///
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy
   @JoinColumn(name="orderBy")
   Users orderBy;

   ///
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.Lazy
   @JoinColumn(name="orderTo")
   Users orderTo;

}
```

I am thinking to create two fields in `Users` Table such that

```
class Account{
    ///
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderTo")
    List<Orders> ordersReceived;

    ///
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.Lazy)
    @JoinColumn(name="orderBo")
    List<Orders> ordersPlaced;

}
```

But again, I am not sure what cascading shall i use. My `Users` table will be populated by some other processes so `orders` has nothing to do with. I don't want when i am placing an order, that particular transaction should add/delete anything. HOWEVER, i might need to update a specific field of `User` whenever i place an order.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest to avoid to use cascade at all (if possible)... When you place an order, you should follow the following steps:

1) load your user from your database

2) create your order ...

3) linkup your order to your user (this is, `order.setOrderBy(user)`)

4) persist your order with your `EntityManager`.

5) Change your user attribute.

From my experience, Cascade should be used carefully. I only used it for persist entities in one shoot (`Cascade.PERSIST`) (example: persisting a newly user with another new entities like orders)

Comment: Thanks, so i shouldn't specific `cascade` at all ? What are the default `cascade` values for an entity if i don't specify anything ?

Comment: There is no default ... so it will something as Cascade "Nothing" ! (Please, if you think this was helpful, don't forget to vote for me !)